# new java question not showing up in new questions, but in homepage

Tags: bug, status-norepro, homepage, newest-questions

I noticed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139493/find-first-word-after-string-match) is showing up in the homepage, but not in newest java questions, even though it is brand new.

What is happening?

Comment: Newest question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) is 12 minutes old as I type this - looks like something got hung up at 3:00 UTC.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. And now it's back.

Comment: I really wonder what happened.

Comment: My uneducated guess is: the tag engine had too much to drink.

Comment: @Shog9 Why is that uneducated?

Comment: 'cause I ain't gonna pretend to understand what makes this thing work. Drunk pixies & unicorn farts are the easy explanation.

Comment: Hey, look - "find first word" made it through the pipeline finally.

Comment: Caching, perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have restarted all tag engines and will continue to monitor them for a bit.